# opengl es 3.0 unsigned integer texture seems to be downscaled

Tags: opengl-es, integer, textures, shader

I'm working with opengl es3.0 on imx6 SOC and here is my problem :

I would like to render to texture with integer format and perform bitwise operation in the fragment shader.
Before to perform bitwise operation I need to get the texture in unsigned integer format.

To do this, here is how I configure my framebuffer object :

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_uiFrameBufferObject);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_uiFrameBufferObject);
glGenTextures(1, &m_uiTextureFB);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTextureFB);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8UI, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTextureFB, 0);

glDrawBuffers(1, attachments);    //GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
```

Then here is the texture used for teh rendering :

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_uiTextureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTextureId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, WIDTH_IN, HEIGHT_IN, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, cImage);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,  GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
```

where cImage is a char table containing a vertical ramp (0 to 255).

To get back my rendering I use the function glReadPixels like this :

```
glReadPixels( 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)Image );
```

Then this is my fragment shader :

```
#version 300 es
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
  precision highp float;
#else
  precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform usampler2D s_textureCamera;
in vec2 g_vVSTexCoord;
out uvec3 out_color;

void main()
{
out_color.rgb = texture( s_textureCamera, g_vVSTexCoord ).rrr;
}
```

This is what I want to have :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT6kr.jpg

And this is what I really have :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VXsA.jpg

I don't know why I have this result. Do you have any idea?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it seems that I can't use floating texture and then integer... If I configure the first texture as GL_RGBA8UI it works.

Is there some tutorials or explanation on texture and format? because I already did some mistakes on format and internal format and for me the specs isn't enough understandable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `R8` texture sampler is a single channel unorm floating point texture; i.e. it will return a float value between 0 and 1. If you cast this to an integer value then, like C code on a CPU, it's either going to be 0 or 1.

If you want to feed in an integer texture then you need the texture you are reading to be `R8UI`, not `R8`.

If you need to use a unorm texture then you just need to rescale the float so the cast to integer expands to fill the range you expect.

```
void main()
{
  out_color.rgb = texture( s_textureCamera, g_vVSTexCoord ).rrr * 255.0;
}
```